# How to get data using table cell value ? PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a trickie cell table. with this values:

```
<tr >
        <td>
            Sensación Térmica:<br>
            Viento:<br>
            Visibilidad:<br>
            Calidad de la nieve:<br>
            Última Nevada:  <br>
            Precipitados Últimas 24Hs:<br>
            Altura de la Nieve:<br>
        </td>

        <td>-2 ºC<br>
            5-10 Km/h<br>
            Buena<br>
            -----<br>
            07/06/2017<br>
            15 cm.<br>
            20 cm.<br><br>
        </td>
```

I need the last value (20 cm.) from the second td.

I use a HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+ called [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) with this code inside a php file

```
$cm = $html->find('td', 1);
```

But this fetch all the values inside the cell. Any help?

Comment: `$var = explode('<br>', $cm)` should put the 20 cm. value you're looking for  at `$var[6]`

Comment: [ParseHTML](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)... Maybe?

Comment: You want the 6th line of an HTML element text.

Answer (score 1):

*I need the last value (20 cm.) from the second td.*

you can achieve this with `Jquery` by getting the value of your second td. then split its value by `<br>`, then get the last element of it

```
var data = $('tr td:nth-child(2)').html();
var dataSplit = data.split('<br>');
var result = dataSplit[dataSplit.length - 2];
alert(result);
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/f7711c15/